# Is it possible to fix incrementation quantity in enum in C#?

Tags: c#, enums

I have for example enum like below.

> public enum City { NewYork = 0, LosAngeles, LasVegas }

Default incrementation step is set to 1, so I'll have values: 0,1,2.
Is there a method, to change this incrementation step, to for example 2, so I could have 0,2,4...?

Comment: No, you have to assign values explicitly in such case - `LosAngeles = 2, LasVegas = 4`.

Comment: Although unless you're making this a flags enum (an enum where multiple values can combine together), this is probably a bad idea, given that the only other reason that I can think that you'd be doing this is to assign a numerical score relating to other functionality inside your enum. Enums should be independent of what uses them. If it is a flags enum, you would want 1, 2, 4, with a value "None" at the zero point, and the [Flags] attribute above the enum.